# Archiving fails, Error Message: "Could not create archive-file due to an error during the packaging-process"

Tags: android, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019, androidx, archiving

**Basic Information:**

App development done in:

Xamarin.Android (Visual Studio 2019)

Using the new AndroidX Packages and google.com.android.material and others.

---

**Situation:**

I´m currently trying to Archive the App I´m developing

but for some reason whenever I try to archive the apk,

the process stops after 10-20 seconds, telling me an error occurred.

> "For more details check the Error Section"

But all the Error Section tells me is something like this:

> "Could not create archive-file due to an error during the packaging-process"

---

**What I´ve tried:**

1. Unloading and reloading the Project.
2. Cleaning and Recreating the Project.
3. Toggling on & off different Settings located in the Android Options.
4. Other minor things I've read on different Blogs and SO Answers to similar problems.

Tried archiving after every single step and after combining multiple steps.

But nothing seems to help.

---

**The Xamarin Diagnostics Console Output is as follows:**

```
[D:RunShellCommand]:      29f162ec30017ece cat /data/system/packages.xml
[D:RunShellCommand]:      29f162ec30017ece cat /dbdata/system/packages.xml
[D:RunShellCommand]:      29f162ec30017ece "pm" "list" "packages" "-f"
```

**The Xamarin Console Output:**

```
Das App Bundle "GLA.NachbestellApp.Droid" wird archiviert...
Archivverzeichnis 'GLA.NachbestellApp.Droid' wird erstellt...
Verzeichnis 'C:\Users\c.adam\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\Archives\2020-01-02\GLA.NachbestellApp.Droid 1-02-20 2.57 PM.aabarchive' wird erstellt...
Dateien '*.aab' werden gelöscht...
'GLA.NachbestellApp.Droid' wird verpackt...
Die Archivdatei kann nicht erstellt werden, weil beim Paketierungsprozess Fehler aufgetreten sind.
Fehler beim Erstellen des App-Archivs "GLA.NachbestellApp.Droid".
```

Comment: You could check the suggestion in the link. https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/3714#issuecomment-537306252 It provides the ways to check for that possibility or other potential problems, you can gather the diagnostic MSBuild output for the packaging and signing steps.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT Followed the steps mentioned in your link, but I couldn't get more Information about the problem. 
(Edited my Question to show the Xamarin Diagnostics Output)
After that the process stops with the already mentioned error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After one more day of trying different solutions the Archive/Signing Process was tested on another PC with Visual Studio 19 installed, there didn't seem to be any errors,

The problem seems to have something to do with the PC/Visual Studio installation it was tested on.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. You could repair the VS. Do not forget to accpt the answer.

Comment: Had the same error. I restarted VS and it also fixed the problem.